# How do I ask user for name then check if it is correct with the user?

Tags: python

How do I ask user for name then check if it is correct with the user? I have tried a lot of different ways to do this but this one has been the best one I have done:

```
Name = input("What Is Your Name: ")
Answer = input("Name Inputted Is", Name, "Is This Correct(enter yes or no): ")
if Answer == yes:
    print("good thank you")
if Answer == no:
    print("Please Reset Your Name")
        Name = input("What Is Your Name: ")
        Answer = input("Name Inputed Is", Name, "(there is not another reset)")
```

This dose not work please let me know  what is wrong.

Comment: `Answer == 'yes'` , `Answer == 'no'`

Comment: `input("Name Inputted Is " + Name + "Is This Correct(enter yes or no): ")`

Comment: Please don't say "does not work."  Instead, say what it does.  How does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

`yes` and `no` need to be strings as well so simply do

```
if Answer == "yes":
```

And

```
if Answer == "no"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with your code:

1. You are using comma `,` in your input function for defining `Answer`, you should use `+`:

   ```
   Answer = input("Name Inputted Is " + Name + " Is This Correct(enter yes or no): ")
   ```
2. You are treating `yes` and `no` as objects, you should not do this. You should treat them as string and use `"yes"` and `"no"` instead. Plus note that the comparison you are making is case sensitive, so if the user puts `"YES"`, your code will not print anything. You can use `.lower()` to do a case insensitive comparison:

   ```
   if Answer.lower() == "yes".lower():
       print("good thank you")
   ```